# Accessing an element of a member of a structure to compare

Tags: c

Question: For the code below, I am trying to compare individual elements of the Logger->Name and not the whole array to the Base_PN variable. Can someone make some suggestions of how I can changes so that I can achieve this. Thanks.

The code below is for my the logger.h file where i declare a new type of 8 bit UINT8 array called partNum_t which is 10 bytes wide or has 10 elements. Then I made it part of a structure or a member of a structure called logger. I know whenever I call the structure member, actually I am actually passing a memory address for example logger->Name will have a memory address. Same with logger->qty.

```
//logger.h
typedef UINT8 partNum_t[10];

typedef struct 
{
   partNum_t Name; 
   UINT16 qty; 
} Logger;

UINT8* connected(void); //Function Prototype
```

The code below is the logger.c file.

```
#include "logger.h"
//Please note that although the type for Logger->Name is partNum_t the PIC32           MPLAB compiler throws errors if the partNum_t* is used instead of UINT8* as it is on the next line.  
UINT8* Get_PN (void)
{
  return (Logger->Name); 
}
```

The next file is the uses the information. I have called it DisplayInfo.c

```
#include "logger.h"
..
..
partNum_t Base_PN={'1','2','3','4','5','-','7','8','9','0'}; 
UINT8* RawValue_PN;
BOOL setFlag; 

void use_PN()
{....
...

RawValue_PN = Get_PN();
if ( RawValue_PN && !memcmp(RawValue_PN, Base_PN, 10))
{
    {
    setFlag=1;
    }
    else 
    {
    setFlag=0;
    } 
}
```

All of above works fine but I am only interested in comparing the last 4 digits '7','8','9','0' of the Base_PN individually. 
     partNum_t Base_PN={'1','2','3','4','5','-','7','8','9','0'}; 
How can I achieve this.

I have tried to 
    UINT8 Get_PN6 (void)
    {
      return (Logger->Name[6]); 
    }
and in the DisplayInfo.c file

```
.....
partNum_t Base_PN={'1','2','3','4','5','-','7','8','9','0'}; 
BOOL setFlag;
UINT8 RawValue_PN6, BL6_current;
RawValue_PN6 = Get_PN6();
if (BL6_current != RawValue_PN6) //So that code only runs when there is change.
{
  if (RawValue_PN6==3)
   {
    setFlag=1;
    }
    else 
    {
    setFlag=0;
    } 
 BL6_current = RawValue_PN6;
}
```

But I get a warning: comparison between pointer and integer for this line

```
if (BL6_current != RawValue_PN6)
```

Comment: How about `memcmp(RawValue_PN + 6, Base_PN + 6, 4)` to compare 4 bytes, starting at the 6th instead of 10 bytes starting at the 0th?

Comment: That would work but I need individual access to each byte so I can compare each one and and then display individual character.

Comment: @ Dmitri I got rid of the Warning about comparison between pointer and integer by using typecasting: [link](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m730887.aspx?tree=true)_italic_ **bold `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know whenever I call the structure member, actually I am actually
>   passing a memory address for example logger->Name will have a memory
>   address. Same with logger->qty.

Your problem comes from a misconception here. It's not *whenever*, but (from ISO/IEC 9899:201x):

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
>   operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’
>   is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that
>   points to the initial element of the array object and is not an
>   lvalue.

So, what you believed to know applies to arrays, but not to *an lvalue that does not have array type*, particularly not to `logger->qty` and `Logger->Name[6]`, which are *converted to the
value stored in the designated object*.

> I am only interested in comparing the last 4 digits '7','8','9','0' of
>   the Base_PN individually. partNum_t
>   Base_PN={'1','2','3','4','5','-','7','8','9','0'}; How can I achieve
>   this.

You can use

```
UINT8 *Get_PN6(void) { return &Logger->Name[6]; }
```

or

```
UINT8 *Get_PN6(void) { return Logger->Name+6; }
```

(which are equivalent), or, as suggested by Dmitri, stay with `RawValue_PN = Get_PN()` and

```
    memcmp(RawValue_PN+6, Base_PN+6, 4)
```

> That would work but I need individual access to each byte so I can
>   compare each one and and then display individual character.

You do already have *individual access to each byte* through `RawValue_PN[6]`, `RawValue_PN[7]`, `Base_PN[6]`, etc.

> I got rid of the Warning about comparison between pointer and integer
>   by using typecasting

This way is wrong. By converting an `UINT8` to an `UINT8 *`, you are reinterpreting a character value (e. g. '7') as a memory address, which is most probably fatal for your program and certainly not what you want.